# Does these Kanjis with "supposedly" English alphabets inside exist?

Tags: kanji, calligraphy

A random [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PawSnZxq3Kc) popped out in my feed that showed a man writing these Kanjis:

[image]

These Kanjis "supposedly" has English alphabets inside. Are these Kanjis real or these are just made up Kanjis written for calligraphy purposes?

Comment: Note also that the title mentions a person who’s returned to Japan and therefore puts letters in the kanji by mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The kanji are "real" in the sense that anyone who can read Japanese would recognize what they are supposed to be. 齋, 藤, 愛, and 結, respectively. However, the correct way to write them does not actually include English letters... that's just a "cute" variation the person who made the video came up with, since the parts do resemble some letters in some ways.

Answer (score 5):

Supplementing Leebo's answer, the real one using a close enough font looks as follows. Most probably it will be recognized as a female name (read e.g. Saito Ayu).

[image]